# C++ multiple actions at once

Tags: events, c++-cli, action, handles

I'm making a program and I have a lot of labels that when you click on them they do the same thing and instead of writing them around 40 times is there a way to reduce it

```
private: System::Void lblHB15_Click(System::Object^  sender,  System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if (HBColumn1 == true) {
        drop (1);
    }
    if (row1 == 6) {
        btnRow1->Enabled = false;
        HBColumn1 = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give us a clearer question

Comment: I want to combine multiple actions. I know in Visual Basic it's done by `Handles lblHB14.Click, lblHB13.Click` but I do not know how to do this in c++

Comment: BTW you *never* should write: `if (x == true)` because: `if (x)` will suffice, maybe `if (HBColumn1 != 0)` would make more sense to the reader (i.e. *you*)?

Comment: In this case it works best for me to see true or false because it tells me if the label should be enabled or disabled

Comment: but I still do not know how to have a `Handles`

Comment: well in that case just get used to `if (HBColumn1)` meaning: if `HBColumn1` is `true` then...

Comment: still don't understand your question, please elaborate.  Maybe show the VB code you're trying to emulate.

Comment: `Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click, btnClickme.Click`

Answer (score 0):

So, your (Matthew's) situation was:

- You were working on a **GUI** C++ coding.
- You have so many visible and **clickable "Label" objects** (a basic concept of showing a squared area painted by a background color, with a text inside the area painted by a foreground color) on the screen with **their own id(name)**:
  `lblHB1`, `lblHB2`, `lblHB3`, `lblHB4`, ... , `lblHB15`, and so on.
- Each of them has its own linked event (void functions):
  `lblHB1_Click(...)`, `lblHB2_Click(...)`, `lblHB3_Click(...)`, `lblHB4_Click(...)`, ans so on.
- And you have trouble, because it is **not** an efficient way to write every individual label's own click event.

The solution is:

- You have to merge the objects first, to make things a lot easier.
- Name the labels by exactly the same string. Yes, overlap the **name of objects** of the same kind like those labels.
- Then, in your screen / IDE / developer tool set each to a **unique "index number"** of the objects with the same id (name), in any specific order that you wish.
- As a result, you will have access to those labels with their names like:
  `lblTitle[0]`, `lblTitle[1]`, `lblTitle[2]`, `lblTitle[3]`, and so on. Yes! The labels are now declared as **an array** of label objects.
- Having set the names and index numbers like this, the event will forward the only one function: `lblTitle_Click(...)`. In this case, the parameter of click function must contain the index of the object. Your developing tool and API must have a specific way to deliver this expression.

Find and study the "indexing" and "event-handling the same kind of objects with the same name".

Comment: I removed some of the non-answer parts, and improved the formatting for clarity.